# How to capture update event of Select2SingleSelectField in Turbogears?

Tags: python, ajax, turbogears2, toscawidgets

There are two `SingleSelectField`s in a form, say `Select2SingleSelectField1` and `Select2SingleSelectField2`. The values of both fields are retrieved from DB. The content of `Select2SingleSelectField2` depends on the selected value of `Select2SingleSelectField1`.

In the controller how to capture the value of `Select2SingleSelectField1`? Could anyone help with this? Thanks.

I am using Turbogears 2.3.3 and Toscawidgets 2. There is no documentation about the parameters on Toscawidgets website. Nor is there on Turbogears website. The only piece of information is Toscawidgets 1's `AutoCompleteField` example http://turbogears.org/2.0/docs/main/ToscaWidgets/Cookbook/AutoComplete.html.

You can capture the event by setting the parameter **`completionURL`**.

```
from tw.jquery.autocomplete import AutoCompleteField

autoField = AutoCompleteField(
               id='myFieldName',
               completionURL = 'fetch_states',
               fetchJSON = True,
               minChars = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear to me what's your situation as you stated you are using ToscaWidgets2 but your code example relates to `tw.jquery.autocomplete` which was from TW1 and your single select is named "Select2SingleSelectField", which makes me think that you are actually using `tw2.jqplugins.select2` which has nothing to do with `tw.jquery.autocomplete` as it was implemented using **jQueryUI** and not **Select2** :)

As far as I can see `tw2.jqplugins.select2` does not much apart wrapping the selection field with jQuery.select2 so the standard [Select2 documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) applies as you can get a reference to the select2 from javascript and use as you normally would.

Otherwise you might want to try [axf.AjaxAutoCompleteField](https://bitbucket.org/axant/axf/overview#rst-header-ajaxautocompletefield) which has little bit more documentation (not much but at least there is an example) which is still implemented on Select2.

In any case both `tw2.jqplugins.select2` and `axf.AjaxAutoCompleteField` do not provide any particular support for depending from other fields (which in case of axf is provided by `AjaxSingleSelectField`) so on that part you will have to roll your own custom solution.

Comment: I'm new to TG. My initial thought was to implement that the content of a singleselectfield was depending on another singleselectfield. The naive design would be: **1**, the client sends ajax request to the server. **2**, the server captures the update event of the singleselectfield. **3**, the server sends back the data through ajax response to the client. **4**, the client updates the other singleselectfield by the callback function.